# Defining a C# class that varies sometimes between int and a dictionary

Tags: c#

```
using System.Web.Script.Serialization;

public class AfValue
{
    public DateTime timeStamp { get; set; }
    public int value { get; set; }
}

public class AfValues
{
    public List<AfValue> items { get; set; }
}
```

I defined my class above and I get data that looks like the one below and I'm having a problem. How do I handle that part in the middle of the data? For the most part the Value is an integer; however, sometimes it is a dictionary and I want to get the Value in the dictionary.

```
{
  "Items": [
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:23:55.3390808Z",
      "Value": 16
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:31:22.0117492Z",
      "Value": 1
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:32:07.9333343Z",
      "Value": 16
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:34:15.0780029Z",
      "Value": {
        "Name": "Bad Input",
        "Value": 255,
        "IsSystem": true
      }
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:41:52.4217834Z",
      "Value": 16
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:41:56.4251708Z",
      "Value": 8
    },
    {
      "Timestamp": "2018-08-30T02:42:06.6542053Z",
      "Value": 24
    }
  ]
}
```

Edit: I am not sure if this is the same as the other problem. I can't map that solution to my problem.

Also, I can't use JSON.net. We have to use System.Web.Script.Serialization.

Comment: What do you want to do with that data?

Comment: You can use the type `object` and check the type of the value after deserialization.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Deserializing JSON with different object types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25196425/deserializing-json-with-different-object-types)

Comment: @nicomp, I'm using this in SSIS, in a Script Source Component to get the data and to output it. I have an Int data output to which I am mapping that data member.

Comment: @progman, I am getting an error from the compiler when I am trying to map the value to an integer column when I am declaring the value as object.

Comment: @RaminMelikov Please edit your question to include a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which can be compiled and tested by others as well as the full error message you get from the compiler.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `Json.NET` which has [`JsonConverter`](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/CustomJsonConverterGeneric.htm), declare `Value` as a class with three properties, for integers just read the integer and convert it to a `Value` instance with setting it's relevant property.

There is an example in the linked documentation, pay attention to `ReadJson` method which does the conversion from `string` to `Version`:

```
public override Version ReadJson(JsonReader reader, Type objectType, Version existingValue, bool hasExistingValue, JsonSerializer serializer)
{
    string s = (string)reader.Value;

    return new Version(s);
}
```

What you need to do is get `reader.Value`, check if it's a single integer or an object and return an instance of the class you created for the `Value`.

Comment: We can't use JSON.net. We have to use the one that is a part of the .NET framework.

Comment: @RaminMelikov: but the one included in the framework is horribly broken.  JSON.NET isn't.

Comment: Even Microsoft recommends to use JSON.Net over the Data Contract Serializer.

Answer (score 0):

It  looks like you are trying to mimic OSIsoft's AFValue and AFValues, including the SYSTEM State Set which has "Bad Value" among other.  A couple of things to note.

- In OSIsoft's AF SDK, the [AFValue](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/T_OSIsoft_AF_Asset_AFValue.htm).Value property is an object, which
  is why it can be a variety of different things.
- Also in the AF SDK, [AFValues](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/Html/T_OSIsoft_AF_Asset_AFValues.htm) implements List rather than it within a property.
- While you may think of it as a dictionary, the SYSTEM state set is actually more of an enumeration.

Others here will focus on your stated problem, but keep in mind that an AFValue can be Int16, Int32, Int64, Single, Double, String, DateTime, an enumeration value, or other things.  Particularly in the process controls world, I would tend to see Single or Double as they represent measurements coming from sensors, more so than an integer.

Though you seem to be using PI Web API, I would encourage to check out the [Live Library](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-AF-SDK/html/1a02af4c-1bec-4804-a9ef-3c7300f5e2fc.htm) for Help on AF SDK.  You may also want to see help for [PI Web API](https://techsupport.osisoft.com/Documentation/PI-Web-API/help.html) Reference.

You may want to investigate the [PI Web API Client Library for DotNet](https://github.com/osimloeff/PI-Web-API-Client-DotNet) on GitHub.  It already has done much of the heavy lifting for you.

Finally, I know you have an account on PI Square, so this type of question is more than welcome in [PI Developers Club](https://pisquare.osisoft.com/community/developers-club).

Rick Davin from OSIsoft

Comment: @RaminMelikov OSIsoft recommends and strongly encourages that you use JSON.Net with our PI Web API.